# Not able to add new CCK field to custom content type

Tags: entities

Today all of a sudden I found out that I can no longer add custom CCK fields to any of my custom content types. The right most drop down box to select the field type is now disabled!!

[image]

When I try to add to the field anyway, I get an error: 
**Add new field: you need to select a widget.** But I just can't select the widget type. The combobox is disabled.
[image]

Any ideas on why is this happening? We are running Drupal 6.22

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely either JavaSript or AJAX failure is giving you problems. Check your browser Javascript error messages with a tool like Firebug, and check your server log.

Alternatively you can disable the javascipt enabled interface entirely.

Comment: Thanks. It turned out that there was jQuery version conflict on the site.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue. I disabled javascript in my browser (firefox), then added the cck fields that I needed and then re-enabled the javascript. Its not a complete solution but a quick one if needed. Obviously, its a javascript issue.

Muhammad.